# Calling Git Binary From Python And Error Codes

Tags: python, git, bash

I am trying to build a set of git utilities with python.  I am using subprocess.Popen to run the git binary.  Right now I am just trying to find the best way to determine that there was an error in running a git command.

My question is whether or not git will always return a returncode of 0 on a successful git command and always return a returncode of non-zero on a unsuccessful call?  I just want to make sure that checking the returncode is a safe way to detect an error so that I can exit the script if a git command was unsuccessful.

Comment: Have you taken a look at any of the Git modules for Python? Any reason not to use them?

Comment: I have heard that they are subpar.  I am very comfortable with the git binary in command line so I would figure this would be the best option.

Comment: Well ideally yes it should be easy to interface with the binary, however it depends on how you define an error what some users may expect to see might return non zero. You may also run into problems handing errors in your program since the best value you have to work off of (return value) is not as helpful as an exception.

Comment: well as long as the git does only return non-zero in an unsuccessful call, I will just display the output of the call (since that will detail the error that happened in a way the user will be able to understand)

Comment: Well I can't make any hard statements about the return value, I don't see it documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, git (and any well-behaved *nix program) will always return 0 for success and non-zero for failure.  This is *the* paradigm on GNU/Linux systems, and since Git was made by the same person who made Linux, you can bet it follows the convention.

Comment: But how do you define success from the variety of git commands? It's not as simple as `cat` or `grep` and while I agree that it should return the correct values that one would expect I don't see it documented anywhere.

Comment: I can't think of any that aren't quite obvious.  If you have a specific question about a particular command, what is it?  If you don't believe that it returns the "correct values," just try it for yourself--no one here needs to convince you.

Comment: Well all I'm saying is that you cant make the claim that it will always return an expected value. For example if you don't have permission for the directory under git then 128 is returned.

Comment: 128 is an error code.  How is that not expected if you don't have permission for the directory?  Zero is success, anything else is error, as my answer says.  I stand by my outlandish claim!

Comment: Ah! Well how about 2 years ago when running `git status` in a repository would return 1?

Comment: Anyway good answer, I'm typically pedantic before I have had my first cup of coffee. :)